# Nested cursor in a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, cursor, nested-loops

I have a cursor which is

```
CURSOR B_CUR IS select DISTINCT big_id from TEMP_TABLE;
```

This would return multiple values. Earlier it was being used as

```
FOR b_id IN B_CUR LOOP
    select s.col1, s.col2 INTO var1, var2 from sometable s where s.col3 = b_id.col1;
END LOOP;
```

Earlier it was certain that the inner select query would always return 1 row. Now this query can return multiple rows. How can I change this logic?

I was thinking to create a nested cursor which will fetch into an array of record type (which i will declare) but I have no idea how nested cursor would work here.

My main concern is efficiency. Since it would be working on millions of records per execution. Could you guys suggest what would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you would just join the two tables.

```
FOR some_cursor IN (SELECT s.col1,
                           s.col2
                      FROM sometable s
                           JOIN temp_table t ON (s.col3 = t.col1))
LOOP
  <<do something>>
END LOOP
```

Since you are concerned about efficiency, however

- Is `TEMP_TABLE` really a temporary table?  If so, why?  It is exceedingly rare that Oracle actually needs to use temporary tables so that leads me to suspect that you're probably doing something inefficient to populate the temporary table in the first place.
- Why do you have a cursor `FOR` loop to process the data from `TEMP_TABLE`?  Row-by-row processing is the slowest way to do anything in PL/SQL so it would generally be avoided if you're concerned about efficiency.  From a performance standpoint, you want to maximize SQL so that rather than doing a loop that did a series of single-row `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operations, you'd do a single `INSERT` or `UPDATE` that modified an entire set of rows.  If you really need to process data in chunks, that's where PL/SQL collections and bulk processing would come in to play but that will not be as efficient as straight SQL.
- Why do you have the `DISTINCT` in your query against `TEMP_TABLE`?  Do you really expect that there will be duplicate `big_id` values that are not erroneous?  Most of the time, people use `DISTINCT` incorrectly either to cover up problems where data has been joined incorrectly or where you're forcing Oracle to do an expensive sort just in case incorrect data gets created in the future when a constraint would be the more appropriate way to protect yourself.

Comment: * `Temp_table` isn't the temp table. I renamed the original table just for sharing. 2: There is series of business logic being implemented before the inner loop. its something `outer_loop ... logic ... inner loop`. So `Joins` wouldn't work here. 3: The distinct keyword would bring distinct big_id since the pk for the `temp_table` is something else and there could be multiple `big_id` for each pk in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR b_id IN B_CUR LOOP 
  for c_id in  (select s.col1, s.col2 INTO var1, var2 from sometable s where s.col3 = b_id.col1)loop
    ......
  end loop;
END LOOP;
```